# Python Flask - Setting a cookie using a decorator

Tags: python, cookies, flask

I'm trying to write a decorator that checks for a cookie, and sets one if it doesn't exist. This is my desperate attempt to get the idea across.

```
def set_cookie(f):
    def decorated_function(*args, **kws):
        if 'cstc' in flask.request.cookies.keys():
            return make_response(f).set_cookie('cstc', value='value')
        else: 
            return f
    return decorated_function

@main.route('/home')
@set_cookie
def home():
    return render_template('main/home.html')
```

Right now I'm getting error:

```
TypeError: home() takes no arguments (2 given)
```

Answer (score 6):

You have to call the original function:

```
def set_cookie(f):
    def decorated_function(*args, **kws):
        response = f(*args, **kws)
        response = make_response(response)
        if 'cstc' in flask.request.cookies.keys():
            response.set_cookie('cstc', value='value')
        return response
    return decorated_function
```

Comment: Thanks, but now I'm getting this error: `BuildError: Could not build url for endpoint 'main.home'. Did you mean 'main.about' instead?`

Answer (score 1):

Your decorator should look something like this:

```
from functools import wraps

def set_cookie(f):
    @wraps(f)
    def decorated_function(*args, **kws):
        #your code here
        return f(*args, **kws)
    return decorated_function
```

You can also have a look at the official flask documentation: http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.10/patterns/viewdecorators/

Answer (score -1):

```
from functools import wraps

def set_cookie(f):
    @wraps(f)
    def decorated_function(*args, **kws):
          #your code here
          return f(*args, **kws)
    return decorated_function
```

Comment: duplicate with @BBatista comment