# bottle : how to set a cookie inside a python decorator?

Tags: python, python-3.x, http, cookies, bottle

There are some operations that needs to be done before running some routes. For example :

- check if we recognise the user,
- check the language,
- check the location,
- set variables in the navbar (here after named header) of the html

and so on, then make decisions based on the outcome and lastly run the requested route.

I find it hard to use the respose.set_cookie("cookie_name", actual_cookie) inside a decorator. It seems flask has a "make_response" object that works well (see here on stack overflow issue 34543157 : [Python Flask - Setting a cookie using a decorator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34543157/python-flask-setting-a-cookie-using-a-decorator)), but I find it difficult to reproduce the same thing with bottle.

any how here is my attempt that is not working :

```py
#python3
#/decorator_cookie.py

from bottle import request, response, redirect

from other_module import datamodel, db_pointer, secret_value #custom_module

import json

cookie_value = None
surfer_email_exist_in_db = None 
header = None 
db_pointer = instanciation_of_a_db_connexion_to_tables
surfer = db_pointer.get(request.get_cookie('surfer')) if  db_pointer.get(request.get_cookie('surfer')) != None else "empty"

def set_header(func):
    def header_manager():

        global cookie_value, surfer_email_exist_in_db, header, db_pointer                                                                                                                                   
        cookie_value = True #for stack-overflow question convenience
        surfer_email_exist_in_db = True #for stack-overflow question convenience

        if not all([cookie_value, surfer_email_exist_in_db]):
            redirect('/login')

        else:
            header = json.dumps(db_pointer.get('header_fr'))

            response.set_cookie("header", header, secret = secret_value, path = "/", httponly = True)

           return func()
    return header_manager
```

and the main file where the routing goes to

```py
#python3
#/main.py

from bottle import route, request
from decorator_cookie import set_header
from other_module secret_value

@route('/lets_try')
@set_header
def lets_try():

    header = request.get_cookie('header', secret = secret_value)
    print(header) #here I get None
    return template('lets_try.tpl', headers = header)
```

I also tried set the cookie like that :

```py
make_response = response(func).set_cookie("header", header, secret = secret_value, path = "/", httponly = True)
```

But got an error :)
Here is the response doc  : [Response documentation](http://bottlepy.org/docs/dev/api.html#bottle.BaseResponse)

Do you have any clues ?
Thanks

Comment: Aren't you expect it wrongly. You are setting the cookie to go in response and then expecting it to exists in request? This may happen from the next request but not the first one for sure

Comment: Tarun, I am sorry I did not get your comment I am sorry. I am indeed setting the cookie in the decorator, at least I am trying to, and then reading it in the actual route. The way the code is written the order of execution when hitting the route should be run the decorator function (that is to say set cookie), and then running the function under the routing (that is to say getting the cookie). And it's not setting anything, but I don't know why.

Comment: @TarunLalwani I now get your first comment ! :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no issue with your code, what you are missing is understanding is understanding

```
Request 1 [By Browser/No Cookies] -> Request has No cookies -> Response you add cookie header

Request 2 [By Browser/Header Cookies] -> Request has Header cookies -> Response
```

So for your first request `Request.get_cookie` will return `None` but for your second request it will actually return the value

[image: Working fine]

Comment: Ok thank you, from what I understand it's a conception mistake from my side.

Htpp server receive a request and then the client create the response. I can't set the response before the request. I need to set this cookie once and for all during the login process, not before each and every requests.

Comment: I needed to check the http Response documentation stating :" **AFTER** receiving and interpreting a request message, a server responds with an HTTP response message". (https://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec6.html)